# How to combine using grunt-contrib-compass and grunt-contrib-cssmin

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using `grunt-contrib-compass` to process my `.SCSS` files

```
compass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      cssDir: 'www/styles',
      sassDir: 'www/styles',
      imagesDir: 'www/images',
      javascriptsDir: 'www/scripts',
      force: true
    }
  }
},
```

And I'm using `grunt-contrib-watch` to watch which file has been changed.

```
watch: {
  compass: {
    files: [
      'www/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'
    ],
    tasks: ['compass']
  }
}
```

After generting the `.CSS` files, I want to minify it using `grunt-contrib-cssmin`. But when I do it like `tasks: ['compass', 'cssmin']`, the second time I need to minify the file, it doesn't override it, it appends instead. So if the first time the file is 10kb, the next time I save it become 20kb and so on and so on..

What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Why don't you simply use compass' `output_style = :compressed` ? It generates minified css already.

Comment: That's handy..never heard about it before..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grunt-contrib-clean to delete everything in the target directory before each compilation:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean

Run the task just before `compass`, and you'll be sure to avoid any conflicts with your old code.

Answer (score 1):

Compass can also minify the files; `output_style = :compressed` check Compass's [Configuration Reference](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/) for more on this.

I prefer to use `config.rb` instead;

```
compass: {
    dest: {
        config: 'config.rb',
        force: true
    }
},
```

Comment: Same here. Less configuration